# TestNG - how to run the same method at the end of each test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have something like:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void test1() {
    testSomething1();
    Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}
    
@Test(priority = 2)
public void test2() {
    testSomething2();
    Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}
    
@Test(priority = 3)
public void test3() {
    testSomething3();
    Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}
```

and I would like to move `Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists())` to `BaseTestCase` or to `TestListener` so I will not have to pass it every time at the end of the test.
I tried to move it to TestsListener to `onFinish` but method `errorsExists()` requires driver and I have problems to get it in there.

Update:
I want to method errorsExists() influence test result. Lets say that in test2 method errorsExists return true -> I want to have following results:
test1 passed
test2 failed
test3 passed

so as far as I know I cannot put this method to any @After annotations and I cannot put it to onTestFailure or onTestSuccess in TestListener

Comment: You could move AfterMethod to the base class. But it's not correct to do that. Because each test case should be atomic and independent. Each test case validates a different thing and should have different assertions. So generalising the assertion for all test cases is not correct.

Comment: AfterMethod doesn't mark specific Test as failed

Comment: @krpo You could have declared the test listener as an inner class within your test class.

Comment: @GauthamM I tried to put it in onFinish method in TestListener, but I have problem to get driver from ITestContext. iTestContext.getAttribute("WebDriver", driver) doesn't work, I'm still getting nullPointer exception

Comment: @krpo AfterMethod will not mark the test case as failure. Because it is not the actual test case. It's more like a cleanup. Freeing up memory or tearing down something after the test has completed. Please clarify your requirement. Are you trying to get the driver object in the AfterMethod for your assertion?

Comment: ThreadLocal variable/object will solve your issue. But use it with care. I have provided some sample code below for your reference. You can change the TestListener method to OnSuccess based on your preference. As you can see, I have a non-null check inside the test listener method. So if your web driver is closed or inactive during the time the code reaches TestListener class, you will get null.

Comment: The approach that I suggested will still not mark the test case a failure. Only things which gets  executed inside @Test method will mark the test case a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `IHookable` interface to achieve this. This is usually (according to the documentation), used to do some operations before the test start. But it works fine for operations at the end of each test as well.

Create a `BaseTest` which implements this interface and let your test classes extend the `BaseTest`.

```java
public class BaseTest implements IHookable {

    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack cb, ITestResult testResult) {
        cb.runTestMethod(testResult); // invokes the actual test case
        Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move it to a new method annotated with @AfterMethod. Any method annotated with @AfterMethod will be executed after each test method is executed. Something like this should work:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void test1() {
  testSomething1();
  //Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void test2() {
  testSomething2;
  //Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void test3() {
  testSomething3();
  //Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}

@AfterMethod
public void assertError() {
  Assert.assertFalse(errorsExists());
}
```

Comment: I tried to move it to @AfterMethod but that's not exactly what I meant. After moving it there, if the assertion is failed, it doesn't mark the specific test as failed

Answer (score 0):

If you are running each of your @Test methods in parallel, then you can achieve this in the following way. But the pre-requisite is, each
@Test should have its own WebDriver instance. You can use ThreadLocal variable to achieve this. Eg:

```
public class Driver {

    public static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
  
    public static AppiumDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.get();
    }

public synchronized void initalizeDriver(String deviceName, String platformVersion, String port, String udid) {
        if (deviceName.contains("iPhone")) {
            setIOSCapabilities(driver, deviceName, platformVersion, port, udid);
        } else if (deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("pcloudy-apple")) {
            setPcloudyIOSCapabilties(driver,platformVersion);
        } else {
            if (deviceName.contains("R-")) {
                setAndroidCapabilities(driver, deviceName, platformVersion, port, udid);
            } else if (deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("pcloudy-Android")) {
                setPcloudyAndroidCapabilties(driver,platformVersion);
            } else {
                startAndroidEmulator(deviceName, udid);
                setAndroidCapabilities(driver, deviceName, platformVersion, port, udid);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setAndroidCapabilities(ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driver, String device, String platformVersion, String port, String udid) {

        try {
            File sourceDir = new File("src");
            File app = new File(sourceDir, ANDROID_APP_PATH);

            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilties = new DesiredCapabilities();
            desiredCapabilties.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, device);
            
            desiredCapabilties.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.IGNORE_UNIMPORTANT_VIEWS,true);
            driver.set(new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(APPIUM_DEFAULT_URL), desiredCapabilties));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            log.error("Exception in launching the Android Driver " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Method inside the base class to start a new driver instance for each @Test method

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters(value={"deviceName","platformVersion","port","udid"})
public synchronized void executeBeforeTest(String deviceName, String platformVersion,
                                               @Optional("Port Required") String port, @Optional("UDID Required") String udid){
        Driver driverObj = new Driver();
        Thread.currentThread().setName(deviceName);
        driverObj.initalizeDriver(deviceName,platformVersion,port,udid);
        if(Driver.getDriver() == null) {
            driverObj.initalizeDriver(deviceName,platformVersion,port,udid);
        }
    }
```

Finally the TestListener class you are looking for,

```
public class TestListener extends UITest implements ITestListener {
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        log.info("Driver getDriver() value is :: "+Driver.getDriver().toString());
        log.info("Driver getSessionId() value is :: "+Driver.getDriver().getSessionId().toString());
            if (Driver.getDriver() != null || Driver.getDriver().getSessionId() != null) {
                try {
                    if (Driver.getDriver() instanceof IOSDriver) {
                        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver();
                        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("bundleId", DeviceCapabalities.IOS_APP_BUNDLE_ID);
                        final Long state = (Long) js.executeScript("mobile: queryAppState", params);
                        System.out.println("Application state code is :" + state);
                        if (state == 1) {
                            log.error("Application has Crashed");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (!(((AndroidDriver) (Driver.getDriver())).currentActivity().contains("app.name"))) {
                            log.error("Application has Crashed");
                        }
                    }
                    saveScreenshot(Driver.getDriver(),iTestResult);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Exception :: " + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Assert.fail("Test case failed due to exception " + e);
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke some code and modify test results using `IInvokedMethodListener`.

Note, that this is a very simple implementation just based on your code example.
It may need some improvements.

**Test Class:**

```
@Listeners(ErrorsExistsListener.class)
class MyTest {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void test1() {
        testSomething1();
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void test2() {
        testSomething2;
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void test3() {
        testSomething3();
    }

    boolean errorsExists() {
        // some logic
    }
    

}
```

**Test Listener:**

```
class ErrorsExistsListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    @Override
    void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
        if (method.isTestMethod() && result.getStatus() != ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            Object[] instances = result.getTestClass().getInstances(false);
            MyTest myTestClass = (MyTest) instances[0]; // you'll get exception here if set this listener for non-MyTest class.
            try {
                Assert.assertFalse(myTestClass.errorsExists());
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
                result.setThrowable(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```